# Facebook SDK android 4: notify when picture is uploaded

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I've implemented code for share picture on facebook from my app. this is my code:

```
 ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "myType") //custom object
            .build();

    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(my_bitmap)
            .build();
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```

Sharing works, and after picture is loaded, a sound notification is executed automatically by sdk. 
There's a way to notify complete upload as happen using facebook app (show notification on notification bar)?
Because with my code,

Comment: The operation is complete when onActivityResult is called in your activity/fragment, until then, the control remains in the Facebook app.

Comment: I've noticed that OnActivityResult is called when facebook ShareDialog disappear (when user push publish button), and not when picture is uploaded successfully.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Look for FacebookBroadcastReceiver in the HelloFacebook sample app. It shows how to receive notifications from the Facebook app when an upload is complete.